# Querymen search by a field value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using the library : https://github.com/diegohaz/querymen

I want to use it so I can also search by field values. I want to search for all jobs that are completed. An example of a test I have:

```
test('GET /jobs?page=1&limit=2&completed=false 200 ', async () => {
   const { status, body } = await request(app())
     .get(apiRoot)
     .query({ page: 1, limit: 2, completed:false})
     .send({ access_token: session1})
   expect(status).toBe(200)
   expect(Array.isArray(body.rows)).toBe(true)
   expect(body.rows[0].completed).toBe(false)

})
```

On the receiving end however the **completed=false** is completely lost and I am unable to query on a field.

```
 export const index = ({ querymen: { query, select, cursor }, user} ,
 res, next) => {
      ...
```

I've looked through the documentation on querymen and I am unable to find a way of searching for a field with a specific value.